# If I were receive an $80,000 inheritance & want to open a business, what taxes would I owe?

Tags: united-states, taxes, business, inheritance

I am receiving about $80,000 inheritance, and I want to start a business. How much would I be taxed or be deducted if I were to put it into a savings account. Lets say the bank is some well-known bank such as U.S. Bank or Wells Fargo.

Comment: what is the source of the funds: salary, bonus, inheritance, insurance settlement, gift, lottery winnings, selling stock...

Comment: The source is inheritance

Comment: @Abel, make sure you know the laws of the country where the inheritance is coming from. You might need to pay taxes there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be taxed for putting it in a savings account (except on any interest that is subsequently paid). If the money is from a taxable source, then you're liable to pay tax on its receipt whether you then put it in a savings account, stuff it under your mattress or burn it. If you're planning on the basis that you might (by not putting it in a bank) be able conceal its existence from the tax authorities so that you don't have to pay the tax that's due then you're asking for advice on breaking the law, which is out of scope for this forum.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I do not plan on hiding it & breaking the law. If you don't mind answering another question, the money is not coming from a taxable source so what kind of paperwork or questions would need to be asked from me.

Comment: Also to note, where I'm currently at is the U.S. & the money is being received from my family who lives in Africa.

Comment: I hate to have to ask this, but is this family in Africa people you have regular contact with? The reason I ask is that there are a lot of financial scams that originate in west Africa these days and some start with a promise of an unexpected inheritance.

Comment: @Abel OK, in thqt case the answer to your question is clear. The money might be taxable, either in Africa or in the US, but putting it into a savings account won't make it taxable.

Comment: @JohnFx These are close family members that have I keep in contact everyday

Comment: @MikeScott You have been helping me so much, could you also answer what evidence would I need to show that I legitimately got the money.

Comment: @Abel Sorry, I can't answer that. I suggest you speak to someone at the bank where you plan to deposit the money and see what paperwork they would need.

Comment: @MikeScott I think that about does it for all my questions. I really appreciate every answer and spending the time to respond.

Comment: @MikeScott - you may wish to clarify - beneficiaries, tho who inherit money, are not taxed, regardless of the amount. It's the estate that pays the tax before funds are disbursed.